# jquery autocomplete with callback ajax json elasticsearch

Tags: jquery, ajax, elasticsearch, jquery-ui

When is make a response to Elasticsearch this is happening:

http://localhost:9200/hobbie/_search?callback=jQuery112407134696443551507_1568816372627&term=hobby&_=1568816372628.

I really don't know why the callback is in the request. Those anyone knows what i did wrong? It would be a great help.

```
$( function() {
function log( message ) {
  $( "<div>" ).text( message ).prependTo( "#log" );
  $( "#log" ).scrollTop( 0 );
}

var zoekterm = $("#birds").text();
var search_request = "http://localhost:9200/hobbie/_search";    

$( "#birds" ).autocomplete({

  //serviceUrl: search_request,

  source: function( request, response ) {

    $.ajax( {
      url: search_request,
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: "jsonp",
      data: { term: request.term },
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      success: function( data ) {
        response( data );
      }
    } ); 
  },
  minLength: 2,
  select: function( event, ui ) {
    log( "Selected: " + ui.item.value + " aka " + ui.item.names );
  }
} );
```

} );

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The callback is being generated by your `type` that is set to "jsonp". JSONP Data Type is very specific and I suspect not what you are after.

Comment: Suggested review: https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/working-with-jsonp/

Answer (score 0):

I think you are just look to perform a GET with JSON results. If so, consider the following code:

```
$(function() {
  function log(message) {
    $("<div>").text(message).prependTo("#log");
    $("#log").scrollTop(0);
  }

  var zoekterm = $("#birds").text();
  var search_request = "http://localhost:9200/hobbie/_search";

  $("#birds").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
      $.getJSON(search_request, {
          term: request.term
        },
        function(data) {
          response(data);
        });
    },
    minLength: 2,
    select: function(event, ui) {
      log("Selected: " + ui.item.value + " aka " + ui.item.names);
    }
  });
});
```

Try to keep it simple.

See also: [jQuery.getJSON()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/)

Comment: thank you for taking the time to answer me :) This is working for me but gives the next error: localhost:9200/hobbie/_search?term=koken 400 (Bad Request). I had this one earlier in my errors because the request is sending 'term' instead of 'localhost:9200/hobbie/_search?q=koken'. Do you know mabye why this is going wrong?

Comment: @Bennie in your `$.ajax()` you used `term` in the data string. This is why it is being passed. If you want it to be `q`, just change it to `{ q: request.term }`.